# How to set I/O sampling rate to more than 65535 ms (FFFF)

Tags: sample, sampling, rate, xbee

I'm using an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) module series 2 with firmware *ZNET2.5 ROUTER/END DEVICE API*.

I would send an ADC sample, but I saw that the IR parameter can be at the maximum 65535 milliseconds; I read about the IR parameter for collecting more samples before to transmit, but I can't find it in this firmware version.

So is it possible that I can't use a sample rate longer than 65535 ms?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I can use the XBee sleep time:

I set the cyclic sleep period (SP) to AF0 (28 s), the number of cycles to power down I/O (SN) to 4, and the sleep option (SO) to 4, enabling the extended cyclic sleep. In this way, the module sleeps per SP*SN seconds so 28 s * 4 = 112 s.